# What is the purpose of the = operator in Python function annotations?

Tags: python, annotations

From PEP 3107, http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#parameters, I've just noticed some extra syntax for function annotations that  I wasn't aware of and don't quite understand.

```
def foo(a: expression, b: expression = 5):
    ...
```

It's the second portion that I am uncertain about, `expression = 5`. How would you use that in a practical sense? Surely not to specify a default argument, which would already be self-evident.

Comment: As the PEP you link to **says**: *"annotations always precede a parameter's default value"*

Comment: Ah, missed that sentence. Not clear on the downvote though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `= 5` is *not part of the annotation*. It is the default value for a keyword argument here.

If you strip the annotations, what you have is:

```
def foo(a, b = 5):
```

From the [Function definition grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> ```
> parameter      ::=  identifier [":" expression]
> defparameter   ::=  parameter ["=" expression]
> ```

where `defparameter` is a parameter in a function definition; the `"=" expression` follows `parameter`, and the definition for `parameter` includes the `":" expression` section that defines an annotation.

Quoting the [original proposal, PEP 3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/):

> Annotations for parameters take the form of optional expressions that **follow the parameter *name***:
>
> ```
> def foo(a: expression, b: expression = 5):
>     ...
> ```
>
> In pseudo-grammar, parameters now look like `identifier [: expression] [= expression]`. That is, **annotations always precede a parameter's default value** and both annotations and default values are optional.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a default value of the param 'b'.